# Can you backup a replicated database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, backup, transactional-replication

I would like to backup a publication SQL Server database that is being replicated with transactional replication.

Would it cause any issues (with replication or any other issue) if I took a backup of that database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can and you should be backing up your replicated databases (inclusive of the system generated database called `distribution`) just the same as any other databases, to the tolerance of data loss you can afford.

Please follow the guidelines in [Back Up and Restore Replicated Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/back-up-and-restore-replicated-databases?view=sql-server-ver15). But the procedure for backing them up should be pretty much the same as any of your other databases (Full, Differential, and Transaction Log Backups all being available for use - depending on your database's Recovery Model).

There's more specific recommendations to pay attention to in the aforementioned documentation when it comes time to restore those backups, such as:

> Replication supports restoring replicated databases to the **same server** and database from which the backup was created. If you restore a backup of a replicated database to another server or database, replication settings cannot be preserved. In this case, you must re-create all publications and subscriptions after backups are restored.

And the specific steps and guidance in [Publication Database: Read-Only Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/strategies-for-backing-up-and-restoring-snapshot-and-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15#publication-database-read-only-transactional-replication) which you should carefully read through prior to your first restore.